# ¿Cómo seleccionar datos de dos dropdown?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Tengo este código funcionando,pero con un solo DropDownList,el cual me busca por "Marca".Yo también quiero que me busque por "Tipo".

```
SqlDataAdapter da = 
  new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Autos WHERE Marca like '" + 
  DropDownListMarcas.SelectedItem.Text + "%'", conn);
```

Yo quiero usarlo con dos dropdownlist.

Ayuda porfavor.

Comment: Y cual seria el problema?

Comment: Hacer la consulta con los dos DropDown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que tu consulta te busque por **Maraca** y **Tipo** **a la vez**, deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
SqlDataAdapter da =
           new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Autos " + 
                              "WHERE Marca like '" + DropDownListMarcas.SelectedItem.Text + "%' " + 
                              "AND Tipo like '" + DropDownListTipos.SelectedItem.Text + "%' "
                              , conn);
```

Esto te devolvería los Autos de una Marca y un Tipo que hayas seleccionado en los dos DropDownList.

Comment: Al parecer mi error era que faltaba un signo de +,pero gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar parametros en la query, es una pesima practica concatenar en un string

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM Autos 
                    WHERE Marca like @marca + '%' 
                            OR Tipo like @tipo + '%'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@marca", DropDownListMarcas.SelectedItem.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", DropDownListTipos.SelectedItem.Text);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
var dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

como veras se une el parametro con el comodin `%` para indicar que comience con esa seleccion, si quieres buscar en cualquier parte usarias `'%' + @marca + '%'`

Pero remarco nuevamente usa siempre parametros

Comment: Entiendo.Pero.....¿Porqué es una "pésima" práctica eso?

Comment: Porque al concatenar los valores puede tener una vulnerabilidad conocida como `Sql Injection` https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL, ademas de no quedar prolijo el codigo y tener problemas con los tipos de datos